# Android source. Edit Key events

Tags: java, android, system, android-source

I want to reassign event, when user send KEYEVENT_SEARCH. Now it just start search activities in applications and if you press it second time - it doesn't do anything. I have to redefine the event so that the first click opens the search, and the next time it closes. Where can I find android push responses? I try edit it in `frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java` , but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Android keys are processed in the following sequence:

1. PhoneWindowManager:

- interceptKeyBeforeQueueing
- interceptKeyBeforeDispatching

2. Activity: onKeyDown/onKeyUp. App can override the function to handle keys.
3. PhoneFallbackEventHandler: onKeyDown/onKeyUp

Currently, the search key is handled in 2. When handling search key in onKeyUp, firstly check whether the search dialog is [launched](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SearchManager.java;l=783), then choose to startSearch or closeSearch.

Comment: Way 2 does not fit. I cannot change the code of every application. I need to make a default reaction for all applications at once in my android assembly

Comment: You can change frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java. Then it will take effect for all apps. And some apps will intend to  override Activity.onKeyDown to handle search key by itself.